# Editing hosts file of my Mediatemple DV container

Tags: php, curl, mediatemple, virtualization

I have a PHP script in a Mediatemple (dv) server that uses cURL to post data to a remote website. This remote website also resides in a (dv) server and doesn't have a domain name yet. I can only access it through web preview.

I'm planning to edit the hosts file of the first server so it can do cURL. Is this even possible?

Suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the remote server is on an accessible IP (hopefully static or non-changing), then adding it to the host file will allow it to be accessible via a DNS-like means on that server.